# Javascript Change HTML Elements by input

Tags: javascript, html

So im trying to make it so in my input which is maximised at 1000 and minimised at 0.10 basically change an element to the given output of the input then times it by 0.98

Here is what i have so far:

```
        <div id="dicegame">
        <div id="diceholder">
            <h1>
            <div id="diceroller">
                <span id="value" class="lable_value">0</span>
            </div>
            </h1>
            <h3>
                <div class="winchance">1 - 6</div>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="inputholder">
        <div id="input">

            <div class="betamount">
            <b>Gems to bet:</b>
            </div>
            <form class="input-money">
                <b><input id="bet" onkeyup="edValueKeyPress()" type="number" name="bet" style="color: #404040;" class="form-control" min="0.10" step="any" max="1000.00" value="1.00"></b>
            </form>
            <div class="profitamount">
            <b>Profit:<b>
            </div>
            <div id="profit">
            </div>
            <script>
                var input = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")
                function myFunction()
                {
                    x=document.getElementsByClassName("profit");  // Find the elements
                    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
                        x[i].innerText=input * 0.98;    // Change the content
                    }

                }

            </script>
```

Comment: Here is also a preview of the site: http://csgodice.net16.net/

Comment: What is your problem with the code?

Comment: It dosen't do it. if you try it on the website nothing updates, i just want it to output the element into a different element but it multiplied by 0.98

Comment: my function is never called somewhere.

Comment: So how would i go about calling it? just myFunction() ? and would it update everytime i added something into the input?

Comment: "Error: Failed to set the 'innerText' property on 'HTMLElement': The 'input' element does not support text insertion. Don't you check the console..? I guess you should set the `value` property instead. Like `bet.value = input * 0.98;`

Comment: How would i go about doing this? bet isn't defined? unless i use the class name not the id

Comment: You can access all elements through their id directly in JS. You don't need to do `document.getElementById()` Anyways.. if multiple, like your input elements with the same class get them through `input = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");` then do this

Comment: `inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(el, i){
                                                           inputs[i].value = el.value * 0.98;
                                                         });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four main problems here:

1. You are using `getElementsByClassName` when you assigned `profit` as an `id`,
2. You are not getting `input` from anywhere,
3. You forgot to match the function name,
4. `onkeyup` event will be triggered only by keyboard, you are using a range so you want to use `oninput` so this is triggered too when clicking on the arrows.

Here is a version of your code with a solution for those four problems:

```
<div id="dicegame">
  <div id="diceholder">
    <h1>
      <div id="diceroller">
        <span id="value" class="lable_value">0</span>
      </div>
    </h1>
    <h3>
      <div class="winchance">1 - 6</div>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="inputholder">
    <div id="input">

      <div class="betamount">
        <b>Gems to bet:</b>
      </div>
      <form class="input-money">
        <b><input id="bet" oninput="edValueKeyPress()" type="number" name="bet" style="color: #404040;" class="form-control" min="0.10" step="any" max="1000.00" value="1.00"></b>
      </form>
      <div class="profitamount">
        <b>Profit:</b>
      </div>
      <div id="profit">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var input = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
  function edValueKeyPress(event)
  {
    var input = document.getElementById("bet").value;
    var x = document.getElementById("profit");  // Find the elements
    x.innerText= input * 0.98;    // Change the content

  }

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j02rbyyd/1/

*EDIT*

In order to have integer names in the input box and the output you will to first modify the input `bet` so it does not take floats and the function so it returns an integer:

```
<input id="bet" oninput="edValueKeyPress()" type="number" name="bet" style="color: #404040;" class="form-control" min="1" step="any" max="1000.00" value="1">

x.innerText= Math.floor(input * 0.98);
```

Check the complete code at https://jsfiddle.net/gdmdgwwh/

Comment: Thanks :) is it possible to also make it so it cancels decimals / float values and keep it inside the box at all times?

Comment: Do you want to have integer results in the profit or to keep only integer numbers in the input range?

Comment: Have an integer output in both

Comment: I have added another jsfiddle where you can see the example using just integers. I've used `Math.floor` which truncates the decimal part but you can use `Math.round` if you prefer to round it to the closer integer.

Comment: Thanks, but is it still possible to make it a 2 decimal place? so my minimum could still be 0.10

Comment: If you only want the integers in the output, you can just leave your original input `<input id="bet" oninput="edValueKeyPress()" type="number" name="bet" style="color: #404040;" class="form-control" min="0.10" step="any" max="1000.00" value="1.00">` and change just the JavaScript code

Comment: On some numbers it has more than 2 decimal places though, is there a code to change this?

Comment: Ah, ok, you can keep the result limited to 2 decimals multiplying by 100, then rounding and finally dividing by 100: `x.innerText= Math.floor(input * 98)/100;`. See https://jsfiddle.net/cj95fL1o/

Comment: Thank you so much, wouldn't have done it without you!, i have another error if you check my questions if you would be able to check it out as 1 person is confusing me on the whole thing thanks :D